# Javascript - remove a string in the middle of a string

Tags: javascript, string

Thank you everyone for your great help !

Sorry, I have to edit my question.

What if the "-6.7.8" is a random string that starts with "-" and has two "." between random numbers?  such as "-609.7892.805667"?

===============

I am new to JavaScript, could someone help me for the following question?

I have a string `AB.CD.1.23.3-609.7.8.EF.HI`

I would like to break it into two strings: `AB.CD.1.2.3.EF.HI` (remove `-609.7.8` in the middle) and `AB.CD.6.7.8.EF.HI` (remove `1.23.3-` in the middle).

Is there an easy way to do it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: you are also removing the trailing digits in 1.2 __3__ .3 and 6 **09** .7.8. Is that correct?

Comment: Either there is a typo or your results are wrong. I get `AB.CD.1.23.3.EF.HI` and `AB.CD.609.7.8.EF.HI`

Answer (score 1):

```
var s = "AB.CD.1.23.3-609.7.8.EF.HI";
var a = s.replace("-609.7.8","");
var b = s.replace("1.23.3-","");
console.log(a); //AB.CD.1.23.3.EF.HI
console.log(b); //AB.CD.609.7.8.EF.HI
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use 
     
     `str.replace();
     var str = "AB.CD.1.2.3-6.7.8.EF.HI";
     var str1 = str.replace("-6.7.8",""); // should return "AB.CD.1.2.3.EF.HI" 
     var str2 = str.replace("1.2.3-",""); // should return "AB.CD.6.7.8.EF.HI"`

Answer (score 0):

Use split() in [String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
var myString = "AB.CD.1.23.3-609.7.8.EF.HI";
var splits1 = myString.split("-609.7.8");
console.log(splits1);
var splits2 = myString.split("1.23.3-");
console.log(splits2);
```

Answer (score 0):

With regular expressions:

```
s = 'AB.CD.1.23.3-609.7.8.EF.HI'
var re = /([A-Z]+\.[A-Z]+)\.([0-9]+\.[0-9]+.[0-9]+)-([0-9]+\.[0-9]+.[0-9]+)\.([A-Z]+\.[A-Z]+)/
matches = re.exec(s)
a = matches[1] + '.' + matches[2] + '.' + matches[4] // "AB.CD.1.23.3.EF.HI"
b = matches[1] + '.' + matches[3] + '.' + matches[4] // "AB.CD.609.7.8.EF.HI"
```